# What proof techniques have failed for solving the SIC-POVM problem and what new insights have been gleaned from them?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, research-level

The SIC-POVM problem is remarkably easy to state given that it has not yet been solved.  It goes like this.  With dim($\mathcal H$) $=d$, find states $|\psi_k\rangle\in\mathcal H$, $k=1,\ldots,d^2$ such that $|\langle \psi_k|\psi_j\rangle|=\frac{1}{d+1}$ for all $k\neq j$.

The state of the art on the solution I believe is here: http://arxiv.org/abs/0910.5784.  Various constructive conjectures have been given but what existence proofs have been tried and why have they failed?  What insight has been distilled from these attempts?

Comment: There is an item devoted to the problem [here](http://qig.itp.uni-hannover.de/qiproblems/SIC_POVMs_and_Zauner's_Conjecture)

Comment: Thanks for the link Alex.  But, again, it lists numerical results and connections to other conjectures.  My question is why, for example, does induction on $d$ not work?  It is possible to _prove_  an inductive proof is impossible?

Comment: Constructions of SIC for consequent $d$ too different to hope on induction, e.g. see TABLE I in e-print you cited: for $d=3$ there are infinite number of SIC, but for other $d$ only finite number (and the numbers of SIC have rather unpredictable behavior).

Comment: Just mentioned related question on MO http://mathoverflow.net/questions/2897/a-group-action-of-the-heisenberg-group-with-special-symmetries

Answer (score 9):

Het Chris,  For more analytic arguments about SIC's you may want to check out http://arxiv.org/abs/1001.0004 .

I got interested in this problem at some point and talked to Steve. He warned me off, describing the SIC-POVM problem as a "heartbreaker" because every approach you take seems super promising but then inevitably fizzles out without really giving you a great insight as to why.

Comment: Thanks Seth!  That's definitely some useful information.  Side note: the thicker papers always seem to find their way to the bottom of the reading pile.  I'm going to blame gravity.